# How to change container settings in docker dashboard?

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac, kitematic

The docker for mac installer used to install an app called Kitematic. There, I could click a settings icon to change container settings. In Docker dashboard, I've found the inspect view, which shows the same settings, but I can't seem to see a way to change them. Am I missing something?